# Computer won't shut down properly with USB device plugged in

Tags: windows-10, usb, power-supply, shutdown, power

I'm running Windows 10 and recently bought an Audioquest DragonFly Red USB DAC - ever since, the device is of course plugged in constantly so that I don't need to reconnect it each time I start the computer but this resulted in the computer never shutting down properly. Whenever the DAC is plugged in and received power (which it always does as it's always lit up) and I try to power off the machine, it turns off and then immediately restarts. Even then, when I power it down with the power button on the BitLocker password screen, it'll still restart indefinitely, until I finally press and hold the power button at which point it'll power off and stay that way.

Why may that be? It sounds to me like something in the BIOS is keeping the PC from shutting down when it finds a running USB device but to me it looks like everything's fine there (the mobo is Fatal1ty H87 Performance):
[image]

What is causing that behaviour, then?

Comment: Go into BIOS and look for "Wake on anything ..." and shut that down. Make sure the USB key has no startup programs in it.

Comment: Are you certain that it powers down completely (does the PSU fan stop spinning) before spinning back up, or is it getting hung trying to shut down? I ask because I've had wonky USB devices that wouldn't unload, which would just stall the shutdown indefinitely. Are you using a USB hub? Also, what version of Windows 10?

[Here is a Reddit thread that seems to describe something similar](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/eakrrt/a_usb_hub_prevents_windows_shutting_down_properly/), but it won't help much since nobody really responded to it. 
¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your 100% confident PC stays off (after shutdown) when DAC is unplugged now after receiving & using it?
2. Have you updated the BIOS ([v2.60 is latest it appears](https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Fatal1ty%20H87%20Performance/#BIOS))?
3. Why don't you try a static discharge: unplug PC power cord, hold power button 10-30sec, reconnect cord, try to replicate issue again. It's fixed some whacky things in my experience
4. You COULD temporarily try to update 'RTC Alarm...' to disable, as I understand this allows Windows to wake the PC for Updates or Scheduled Tasks to see if those are playing a role maybe with the DAC SW?
5. You COULD temporarily try to update 'Restore on AC/Power Loss' (under Advanced, Chipset Configuration) to disable to see if the PC shutdown process is messed up so BIOS thinking its loosing power?
6. You could try DAC on another PC to see if the problem is really the DAC, could be it's SW, or some glitch suddenly on your PC
7. You could always try to call/email ASRock (manufacturer) to see if they have suggestions
8. There are USB hubs that allow you to power each port so thats another idea if nothing else pans out

Comment: Oh yes, bam, bam, bam right to the points!!!